# ORA-00904: "NEW_SALARY": invalid identifier

Tags: sql

Im Having An Issue with my code in SQL.. pls tell why is the error happening... thnx

Code:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,SALARY,SALARY+1500 NEW_SALARY,SALARY*12 CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,NEW_SALARY*12 NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

I am Getting The Output As:

```
ORA-00904: "NEW_SALARY": invalid identifier
```

Additional Info:
App: https://livesql.oracle.com
Date: 25 July, 2021

Comment: Because `NEW_SALARY` is not yet available in the context of the same`select`. You need to wrap it with another `select` statement or repeat the calculation

Answer (score 1):

Because `NEW_SALARY` is not in the original table,you can not use it directly in another column expression

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,
       SALARY,
       SALARY+1500 NEW_SALARY,
       SALARY*12 CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,
       (SALARY+1500)*12 NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You omitted the comma from the select list to delimit the fields, three times it turns out, the correct query would be:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, SALARY, SALARY+1500,
       NEW_SALARY, SALARY*12, CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,
       NEW_SALARY*12, NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

*Wrapped to make it readable in SO*

Unless you intention was to alias the computed expressions, then you should use the `AS` operator:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, SALARY, SALARY+1500 AS NEW_SALARY, 
     SALARY*12 AS CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,
     (SALARY+1500)*12 AS NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY 
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have a column name NEW_SALARY, you need you to do it like this:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,SALARY,SALARY+1500 NEW_SALARY,SALARY*12 
CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,(SALARY+1500)*12 NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL in general does not allow you to reuse column aliases in the `SELECT` where they are defined.  The traditional solutions are:

- Use a subquery.
- Use a CTE.
- Repeat the expression.

Oracle also supports lateral joins, which can be handy for this:

```
SELECT e.FIRST_NAME, e.SALARY, x.NEW_SALARY,
       e.SALARY * 12 as CURRENT_ANNUAL_SALARY,
       x.NEW_SALARY * 12 as NEW_ANNUAL_SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES e CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT e.SALARY + 1500 as NEW_SALARY FROM DUAL) x
```